# iphone/cocoa custom ui element

Tags: iphone, user-interface, tags

I'm very interested in using the typical mac 'tag' element in an iphone app (see specimen 1 - The Blue round element'). I dont really have any idea of how to implement it except for copying the color and making it a uibutton.
I would like to be able to drag this tag from one 'section' to another 'section'.

Can someone point me in the right direction of how this would be done. Surely a simple library is available somewhere.

Keep it classy stackoverflow.

[alt text http://posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/norskben/mJPxKIUvQHrC3ew3LZS3I2F5poDzq4VefVt5ENgjY3iVH0KFh1ceswpm8RVq/account.png](http://posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/norskben/mJPxKIUvQHrC3ew3LZS3I2F5poDzq4VefVt5ENgjY3iVH0KFh1ceswpm8RVq/account.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This control is called an NSTokenField in Cocoa AppKit.  You can find something similar to start with in the [three20 project](http://github.com/facebook/three20).  The control is called a TTPickerTextField I believe.  You could use that as a basis for your control and add the drag and drop capabilities using the UIResponder methods touchesBegan/Moved/Ended.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new class that is a subclass of `UIView` and add the subviews in the `initWithFrame:` method. Then implement the touch handling methods that you need to create your custom view with dragging behavior.